Construction of Poincaré line bundles
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$
I'm studying the construction of Poincaré line bundles from [1, Chapter IV §2]. By definition, a Poincaré line bundle is any line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $C \times \Pic^d C$ such that for every $L \in \Pic^d C$, one has
$$\mathcal L|_{C \times\{L\}} \cong L.$$
I don't completely follow the construction of $\mathcal L$ given in [1].
Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$ of genus $g = g(C)$. Denote by $\Sym^d C$ the $d$-fold symmetric cover of $C$. Let
$$\Delta \subset C \times \Sym^d C$$
be the universal divisor, i.e. for every $D \in \Sym^d C$,
$$\Delta|_{C \times \{D\}} = D.$$
To define a Poincaré bundle $\mathcal L$ on $C \times \Pic^dC$, [1] considers the map
$$u: \Sym^d C \to \Pic^d C.$$
Restrict to the case $d \geq 2g +1$. Then every line bundle $L$ of degree $d$ has global sections (by Riemann-Roch, since $K \otimes L^\vee$ has negative degree), so that $L \cong \mathcal O(D)$ for some effective divisor $D$. Then $f^{-1}(L) = |D|$ is a projective space of dimension $d-g$, so that $u$ is a projective bundle over $\Pic^d(C)$.
Next pick a point $q \in C$, consider the divisor
$$X_q = \{q + D' \,|\, D' \in \Sym^{d-1}C\} \subset \Sym^d C,$$
and set
$$\mathcal L = (\id_C \times u)_* \mathcal O(\Delta - \pi^* X_q),$$
where $\pi$ is the projection $C \times \Sym^d C \to \Sym^d C$.
Then [1] writes:

We claim that $\mathcal L$ is a Poincaré line bundle of degree $d$. To see this, fix a point, say $\mathcal O(D)$, in $\Pic^d C$; all we have to do is show that $\mathcal O(\Delta - \pi^* X_q)$ restricts, on $C \times |D|$, to the pull-back of $\mathcal O(D)$ from $C$.

I'm a bit confused. Why is $\mathcal L$ even a line bundle? If the last half-sentence is correct, then $\mathcal O(\Delta - \pi^* X_q)$ restricted to $C \times |D| = (\id \times u)^{-1}(\mathcal O(D))$ has lots of global sections (at least $d-g+1 \geq g+2$), and so by Cohomology and Base Change, $\mathcal L$ will not be a line bundle?

[1] Arbarello, Cornalbea, Griffiths, Harris; Geometry of Algebraic Curves, Volume I

$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic}\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}$
I think one doesn't want to push-down the sheaf $\mathcal O(\Delta - \pi^* X_q)$, but rather descent it to $\mathcal L$, i.e. one wants
$$(\id_C \times u)^* \mathcal L \cong \mathcal O(\Delta - \pi^* X_q).$$
If this holds, then $$p^* \mathcal O(D) = \mathcal O(\Delta - \pi^*X_q)|_{C \times |D|} = ((\id \times u)^*\mathcal L)|_{C \times |D|} = p^*(\mathcal L|_{C \times \{\mathcal O(D)\}})$$
where $p: C \times |D| \to C$ is the projection, which gets identified with the map $$(\id \times u)|_{C \times |D|}: C \times |D| \to C \times \{\mathcal O(D)\}.$$
Hence $\mathcal L|_{C \times \{\mathcal O(D)\}} \cong \mathcal O(D)$, as desired.
It remains the question why $\mathcal O(\Delta - \pi X_q)$ descends. Since $\id_C \times u$ is a flat projective map with integral fibers, a line bundle descends if and only if it is trivial on the fibers [cf. Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Exc. III.12.4]. This follows from the last half-sentence of the quote in the question by Arbarello et al.
